# How to exclude only 1 endpoint from the list of endpoints in app.js?

Tags: node.js, express

These are the links-

```
app.get('(/api/v1)?/abcd', abcd.get);
app.post('(/api/v1)?/efgh', efgh.post);
app.get('(/api/v1)?/hijk/:item', hijk.get);
app.get('(/api/v1)?/lmno', lmno.getMulti);
app.delete('(/api/v1)?/pqrs/:item',pqrs.delete);
```

I want to add `app.use()` for all the links excluding `app.get('(/api/v1)?/abcd', abcd.get);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express middleware's get executed in the order you define them and therefore, you can simply do something as below to make sure middleware code you want is not executed for specific endpoint:

```
app.get('(/api/v1)?/abcd', abcd.get);
app.use(<middleware_func>);
app.get('(/api/v1)?/hijk/:item', hijk.get);
app.get('(/api/v1)?/lmno', lmno.getMulti);
app.delete('(/api/v1)?/pqrs/:item',pqrs.delete);
```